# What is HTTP Host Availability in flutter doctor 2.10?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-doctor

When I run `flutter doctor -v` in Flutter version 2.10 stable channel, I get this new check:

```sh
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

It is working alright but exactly is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I found this in the documentation.

It basically makes sure you can connect to hosts needed for Flutter development.

Dart file that answers the question on GitHub: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/eb1a851f5843efb6cecab020467a2ffea48fd1d3/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/http_host_validator.dart

Comment: Yeah and fixed this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49403 which got solved with this pull request adding the feature: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/95386